# the difference between : and / in s/vi/VIM/g and s:^vi$:VIM:

Tags: vim

I read vim regex example

```
s/vi/VIM/g
```

and

```
s:^vi$:VIM:
```

What' the difference between `/` and `:`,
Search but found few helpful materials.

Answer (score 4):

Vim lets you change the character you use to start and end the search pattern arbitrarily. This is useful if you're going to have to escape the slash a lot in a particular expression.

For example, these two commands are equivalent:

```
s/\/\//ss/g
s://:ss:g
```

but the second one is much easier to type and read.

Comment: Let;s me add a pointer to docs: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#E146

Answer (score 1):

The two `:s` commands are different.

`s/vi/VIM/g` replace all `vi` by `VIM` no matter where `vi` is and how many times it occurred.

However, `s:^vi$:VIM:` replace lines containing **only** `vi` two characters by line: `VIM`

Regarding the `/` and `:` they are just separators of `:s` command. They make no difference in your command. If you want to read this part explanation, do `:h E146` in your vim.